# Kubernetes Rollback in Azure Pipeline?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-pipelines, kubernetes-helm

I am doing research and trying to find the best way to perform rollbacks/backouts for applications deployed to Kubernetes through an Azure pipeline. Is there a task I could use to handle this? I understand there might be different methods such as tags, registries, Helm, etc., what might be the easiest in an Azure pipeline?

Comment: Please [accept it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it's helpful for you. And feel free to let me know if you have any further concern :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use official [Kubectl task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes?view=azure-devops) with [rollout undo](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-undo-em-) command to **Rollback to a previous rollout**.

Here's one detailed blog from **Adrian Bumbas** about [this topic](https://adrianbumbas.com/rollback-kubernetes-deployments-with-azure-devops-pipelines/).